# Hardcoding a Button position, yet, he always goes out the margins

Tags: c#, windows, position, location

I've created a `Button`, and I'm trying to fit it inside a dialog window.

It goes like this:

```
 buttonRight.Location = new Point(this.Width - 96, this.Height -buttonRight.Height - 20);
```

It sounds simple and obvious, but today, it isn't

Here's the result: http://puu.sh/hEsTt/ceae1b6302.png

Why? Just why? I have the form height, the button height, a 20 pixels margin and it still doesnt stay above the line. Any ideas?

Comment: It could be that after the button's location is set window's size has changed?

Comment: Did you display / debug any of the values for height and width to make sure they are what you expected ?  If you want a button to always stay in same spot regardless of the forms size then you should place the above code in the form size changed event.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel No, can't be, because it's the last piece of code.

Comment: @deathismyfriend That window size is variable, is a customized dialog box, from dotnetpearls. But! I'm defining the button location after all of the code.

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `Form`'s `Size` instead of its `ClientSize`.

This should fix it:

```
buttonRight.Location = 
       new Point(this.Clientsize.Width - 96, 
                 this.Clientsize.Height - buttonRight.Height - 20);
```

The `Size`, including `Width` and `Height` are the **outer** dimensions. But you want the **inner** dimensions as per `ClientSize` or when needed `ClientRectangle`